# Leading zeroes in Integer array leading to different values being printed

Tags: java, arrays, integer, leading-zero

Why is the value printed not as same as the input? Will leading zeroes change the way an integer is read?

```
Integer[] secondArray = {02,03,04,05,06,011,012,012,0123};

 System.out.println("values:" + Arrays.toString(secondArray));
```

Output: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 10, 83

Comment: What is `011` in Octal? So, yes, a leading "0" has a meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A leading zero in an integer literal in Java (and a lot of other languages) means an *octal* number (base 8).

So `011` is nine.

Other systems you can use are hex (`0x09`, base 16) and binary (`0b1001`, since Java7).

Answer (score 1):

Integers with leading 0 treated as octal (base 8) number.
The conversion goes as follows

```
Octal             Decimal
06         ->     6
07         ->     7
08 (Not a valid octal number)
09 (Not a valid octal number)
010        ->     8
011        ->     9
012        ->     10
```

and so on